# How to always show debug window in XCode6

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'm having trouble keeping my debug window open in XCode6. Every time I run the code the debug window disappears. I then have to press CMD SHIFT Y to show it again or use the upper right window icon. How do I make the debugger window stay at all times?

Comment: `Xcode` -> `Behaviors` -> `Edit Behaviors...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Paul moves his comment to an answer I'll delete mine and upvote his.

Here was a screenshot I was preparing when he got his comment in:

[image: Show Issue Navigator]

You want the "show" issue navigator item checked to on.

Comment: No problem - thanks for fleshing this out into an answer.